# Algorithm to Sort Items Using Relative Predicates

Tags: swift, sorting, predicate

I have set of elements that each have relative predicates which I want to use to properly sort the group. What is the best algorithm/approach to make the following group get sorted correctly to

`[a, c, b, e, f, d]` or `[c, a, b, e, f, d]`?

```swift
[
  a,
  b, // >a and <e
  c, // =a
  d, // >f
  e, // <f
  f, // >a
]
```

I set up my predicates in Swift by doing the following:

```swift
import Foundation

class Item {

  let id: String
  let relations: [String: ComparisonResult]

  var description: String {
    return id
  }

  init(id: String, relations: [String: ComparisonResult] = [:]) {
     self.id = id
     self.relations = relations
  }

}

let items = [
  Item(id: "a"),
  Item(id: "b", relations: ["a": .orderedDescending, "e": .orderedAscending]),
  Item(id: "c", relations: ["a": .orderedSame]),
  Item(id: "d", relations: ["f": .orderedDescending]),
  Item(id: "e", relations: ["f": .orderedAscending]),
  Item(id: "f", relations: ["a": .orderedDescending]),
]

print(items) // [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
print(items.sorted) // [a, c, b, e, f, d]
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica How would I sort my elements based on the relative predicates I apply to each element?

Comment: Oh I missed it in the second line of your question hah. This is fundamentally a graph problem. Your `id`s define a set of nodes. The "relations" are arcs between the nodes. Comparison between two arbitrary elements `a` and `b` consists of finding a path from `a` to `b` in the path. In the easy case, there's a direct relationship. Otherwise, you'll need to use a path-finding algorithm (depth first search will do) which finds a path between the two. Analyzing the path, you can determine if if every step along the way was `orderedAscending`. That's your definition of `<`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica could you provide an answer and/or documentation that could lead me to a solution?

Comment: I can't really point to much besides a computer science or graph theory textbook. I'm implementing this for fun, and can share my results later

Comment: here's a kind of rough example: https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/Topological-sorting-from-a-set-of-rules

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica this is pretty cool, but even though the arc test returns `true` for `f < d`, when the `allItems` is sorted, `d` is before `e` and `f`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210840/discussion-between-alexander-reinstate-monica-and-noodleofdeath).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Alexander Reinstate Monica's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander-reinstate-monica) suggestion in the comments I created a graph theory solution that works as desired below!

```swift
import Foundation

extension ComparisonResult {

    var inverse: ComparisonResult {
        switch self {
        case .orderedAscending: return .orderedDescending
        case .orderedDescending: return .orderedAscending
        default: return .orderedSame
        }
    }

}

extension ComparisonResult: CustomStringConvertible {

    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .orderedAscending: return "<"
        case .orderedDescending: return ">"
        default: return "="
        }
    }

}

class Graph {

    var nodes = [String]()
    var arcs = [String: [String: ComparisonResult]]()

    init(nodes: [String] = []) {
        self.nodes = nodes
    }

    func connect(_ a: String, _ b: String, _ relation: ComparisonResult) {
        var arcs = self.arcs[a] ?? [:]
        arcs[b] = relation
        self.arcs[a] = arcs
        arcs = self.arcs[b] ?? [:]
        arcs[a] = relation.inverse
        self.arcs[b] = arcs
    }

    func connect(_ a: String, _ b: String, _ relation: String) {
        switch relation {
        case "<": connect(a, b, .orderedAscending)
        case ">": connect(a, b, .orderedDescending)
        default: connect(a, b, .orderedSame)
        }
    }

    func compare(_ a: String, _ b: String, _ excluding: [String] = []) -> ComparisonResult {
        if let arcs = self.arcs[a] {
            if let value = arcs[b] { return value }
            for (id, relation) in arcs {
                guard !excluding.contains(id), relation != .orderedDescending else { continue }
                return compare(id, b, excluding + [a, b, id])
            }
        }
        return .orderedSame
    }

    func sorted(reversed: Bool = false) -> [String] {
        return nodes.sorted {
            if reversed { return self.compare($0, $1) != .orderedAscending }
            return self.compare($0, $1) == .orderedAscending
        }
    }

}

extension Graph: CustomStringConvertible {

    var description: String {
        var strings = [String]()
        for (id, map) in arcs {
            strings.append("\(id) -> \(map)")
        }
        return strings.joined(separator: "\n")
    }

}

let graph = Graph(nodes: ["a","b","c","d","e","f"])
graph.connect("b", "a", ">")
graph.connect("b", "e", "<")
graph.connect("c", "a", "=")
graph.connect("e", "f", "<")
graph.connect("f", "a", ">")
graph.connect("d", "f", ">")

print(graph)
print(graph.nodes) // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
print(graph.sorted()) // [a, c, b, e, f, d]
print(graph.sorted(reversed: true)) // [d, f, e, b, c, a]
```